# Convert string.format and timespan to 12-hour format with AM/PM

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, timespan

I have the following code that current gives me a list of timespans with a hour/minute (24-Hour format). I need to change the string.format to show hour/minute AM or PM (12-Hour format).

```
var availableTimes =
                _appointmentService.GetAvailableHours(date, appointmentId)
                    .Select(x => string.Format("{0:D2}:{1:D2}", x.Hours, x.Minutes));
```

How is the best way to do this? I don't see anyway with a timespan.

*Here is the GetAvailableHours method that it uses.

```
public IEnumerable<TimeSpan> GetAvailableHours(DateTime? date, int? appointmentId)
        {
            if (date == null) return null;
            var hours = new List<DateTime>();
            for (var ts = new TimeSpan(); ts <= new TimeSpan(23, 30, 0); ts = ts.Add(new TimeSpan(0, 30, 0)))
            {
                hours.Add(date.Value + ts);
            }

            var booked = _appointmentRepository.Get
                .Where(x =>
                    (!appointmentId.HasValue || x.Id != appointmentId))
                .Select(x => x.ScheduledTime).ToList();
            //return available hours from shifts
            var workingHours = from h in hours
                               from s in
                                   _scheduleRepository.Get.Where(
                                       x => x.ShiftStart <= h && x.ShiftEnd >= EntityFunctions.AddHours(h, 1))
                               where
                                   s.ShiftStart <= h && s.ShiftEnd >= h.AddHours(-1) &&
                                   booked.Count(x => x == h) == 0

                               select h.TimeOfDay;



            //match available hours with another appointment 
            return workingHours.Distinct();
        }
```

Comment: But what about if Hours will exceed 24?

Comment: Is that possible with a timespan?

Comment: Yes, of course. Try this `TimeSpan.FromHours(100);`.

Comment: It doesn't really make sense for a TimeSpan to have AM or PM associated with it. It might make more sense to switch to a DateTime from the TimeSpan object.

Comment: The method is only suppose to return the hours available in the day that there are no appointments between the start and end of the shifts available that day. So maybe timespan isn't the best thing to use here?

Comment: @Ek0nomik how would be the best way to go about that? I agree a datetime would be better.

Comment: @deliriousDev - I added an answer that may help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you could change your code to return an `IEnumerable<DateTime>` pretty easily.

```
//Get your distinct time spans
var distinctTimeSpans = workingHours.Distinct();
//Build date objects from the parameter and time span objects
var dates = distinctTimeSpans.Select(ts => new DateTime(date.Value.Year, date.Value.Month, date.Value.Day, ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds));
```

Then you can call `ToString()` on your `DateTime` object:  `.ToString("hh:mm tt")`

Comment: Ok I got the method changed over, except for changing the Distinct() call (not sure how).

Comment: @deliriousDev - I edited my answer.  I haven't tested the code, but, the idea is there: build your distinct list of `TimeSpan` and then build your list of `DateTime` from that.

Answer (score 7):

```
    [Test]
    public void TimeSpan_PmAmFormat()
    {
        TimeSpan timeSpan = new TimeSpan(23, 20, 0);
        DateTime dateTime = DateTime.MinValue.Add(timeSpan);

        CultureInfo cultureInfo = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

        // optional
        //CultureInfo cultureInfo = new CultureInfo(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name);
        //cultureInfo.DateTimeFormat.PMDesignator = "PM";

        string result = dateTime.ToString("hh:mm tt", cultureInfo);

        Assert.True(result.StartsWith("11:20 PM"));
    }
```